# Fastest way to move multiple terabytes of information

Tags: rsync, migration

I need to move multiple terabytes of information from one NFS system (The NFS system is in AWS) to amazon EFS, but I need it to move that that data the fastest way possible. I've tried rsync, but it takes too long, and I've also tried using parallel with rsync but it does not give me the results I need.

The data consists in multiple directories with many small files

Are there any tried and tested ways to move data very quickly while still making sure that it's not corrupted when it arrives (Like rsync)?

Comment: I can't imagine you are the first to need to do this.  Have you tried contacting Amazon support to see what they recommend?

Comment: We only have the basic support, I do not believe we are entitled to technical support at that level.

Comment: May be worth asking, certainly no harm in asking.  I was in a similar situation with a different company, and casually mentioned that if I had to do all the work to move the data then I may as well move it to $other_provider .... even with no "enhanced" support contract, they had their engineers get with me right quick and they took care of everything - which got them another $750k of our business over a 5 year period.

Comment: Interesting, i'll give it a try

Comment: Note that they may call your bluff... if it is a bluff.

Comment: Are both file systems connected to the same instance? What instance size do you have? The type of instance will affect your network bandwidth.

Comment: How many files, what is the total size, how much time do you have to transfer them?

Comment: @JohnHanley The NFS server has the EFS filesystem mounted on it. I'm trying to move everything as fast as possible between the exports directory and the EFS mount point.  The instance size is c3.8xlarge.

Comment: @JohnMahowald It's about 10TB, mostly small files in multiple directories. I have about a 2 week time limit, but it should be done as fast as possible.

Answer (score 5):

The fastest way to move such large volumes of data is still Sneakernet. Thus, [Amazon Snowball](https://aws.amazon.com/snowball/). This device gets shipped to your location, where it can move up to 80 terabytes of data directly off your local network via a 10 Gigabit Ethernet connection. It then gets shipped back to Amazon where they upload the data into your Amazon account.

Comment: I clarified my question, the NFS server is also in AWS. So it's moving the data from the NFS server in AWS to the EFS mount point. The options I mentioned above just aren't moving the data fast enough.

Comment: Never underestimate the bandwidth of a station wagon full of backup tapes!

Comment: What does that mean: "the NFS server in AWS"?

Comment: @MichaelHampton It means that the NFS server where the files are is an EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

For very many small files the limit will be the IOPS for both the source and the destination storage.  `rsync` won't speed things up as it has to read every file, its main benefit is not transferring already copied chunks of large files.

If you instead restore a backup archive, the reads are larger, sequential, and higher throughput:

```
cd /mnt/files/
tar -xzf /mnt/backup/files.tar.gz
```

However, you have to have the space for this backup archive.

Also, the point in time restored may be some time ago depending on how long it takes to make the backup.